# Are there data/sources on the usage of Swiss German before/after WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, language, switzerland, swiss

Today remarkably across German-speaking countries Switzerland keeps a very high level of usage of dialects other than Standard High German (SHG). Although non SHG-dialects are also commonplace in Austria, it's not on the same level of Switzerland, where Swiss-German appears in everyday life in every situation.

Up to mid 19th Century this was also the case across most of the German *Sprachraum*, although a standardization trend started to appear back then.

One of the reasons commonly cited for Switzerland keeping it's dialects is the "Defensive spirit" of Switzerland during WWII where the Swiss sought to show a different national identity from that of it's neighbors, with increased use of Swiss German, institution of Romansh as a national language, etc.

What I can't find are sources, or data or any sort of information regarding the use of Standard High German in Switzerland between the mid-19th Century and WWII. I'd assume the same pattern of standardization was happening in the country, which was reversed on WWII and kept like this ever since, but I have no sources to check that.

Are there information, sources, etc regarding the usage of Standard High German/Swiss German in everyday life in Switzerland before the rise of Nazism in Germany?

Comment: I think it is rather inverse - the Hochdeutsch was gradually imposed on Germans, but not on Swiss. Still, even today Germans from the areas around Basel speak a dialect similar to that one the Swiss side - at least, this is what some of them told me. Another thing to take into account is [Alsatian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsatian_dialect), which was likewise displaced, but in favor of French.

Comment: Google Scholar shows many potentially relevant publications, the vast majority of them pay-walled. A freely accessible one mentions that turning towards use of dialects was part of "intellectual national defense" during WW2, but without going into details: "Als man in den dreißiger Jahren und in den ersten Jahren des Zweiten Weltkriegs in der Deutschschweiz im Zuge der sog. „geistigen Landesverteidigung” gegenüber Deutschland immer stärker die eigene Mundartlichkeit betonte, begegnete man dieser Bewegung in der französischen Schweiz mit Verständnis, ja sogar mit einem gewissen Wohlwollen, .."

Comment: I'm not a fan of the use of "German-speaking" and "dialects" in the first edit of the question. Languages are made of dialects, and there's no reason whatsoever that the dialect spoken in Switzerland is any more (or less) legitimately "German" than the dialect spoken in Berlin. Editing the question accordingly.

Comment: It's not clear to me that there's an answerable question here. 1) [Swiss Standard German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Standard_German) is generally a written language, while the various overlapping Swiss German dialects are spoken and not written. This was presumably the case well before WWII and "developed as a result of long religious and political isolation from the centers of German linguistic standardization" ([Fergeson 1958, p. 327](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00437956.1959.11659702)).

Comment: 2) There are many different ways in which varieties of Swiss German are shifting over time ([Christen 2009](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/flin.1998.32.1-2.53/html)). So exactly what change are you trying to measure?

Comment: As someone who lives in the rural north of Germany I can tell you that dialectic German (specifically Plattdeutsch) is routinely used by people who grew up in the area. I'm not sure the difference between Switzerland and Germany you suggest actually exists.